# How I can take attribute value from input element and add it to the action link using HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make input field to search for images, and after submitting I should go to "Google's Image Search" which i must.

i inserted the *name=q* attribute but form *tbm=isch* i do not know how to insert it.

```
    <form action="https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch">  
        <input type="text" name="q" class="search">
        <input type="button" value="Image Search" class="sub">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you could do what you need to achieve by using a hidden input like so:

```
    <form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="tbm" value="isch">  
        <input type="text" name="q" class="search">
        <input type="submit" value="Image Search" class="sub">
    </form>
```

In this case, you'd be using a get method on a form, and on submit, you'd send both parameters that you need : `tbm` (with a value set to `isch`) and `q` (with a value set to whatever the user types)

This code worked for me.